# Spring Boot: order of Autowired annotation leads sometimes to circular references

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a Spring Boot Project with multiple Components and Configuration classes. In my Project I noticed that the order of the Autowired fields results in different scenarios. Sometimes I get Nullpointer-Exceptions and Spring Boot is complaining about circular references, but with the right order of the fields everything works fine.

I was able to reproduce my Problem with this simple Code Snippet:

Component1:

```
@Component
public class Properties {

    public String getHost() {
        return "some.address.com";
    }
    public int getPort() {
        return 8080;
    }
}
```

Component2:

```
@Component
public class WebClient {

    @Autowired
    String webadress;

    public void callWebAdress() {
        System.out.println("Getting Data from " + webadress);
    }
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    Properties props;

    @Bean
    String webAdresss(){
        return "http://+"+props.getHost()+":"+props.getPort();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init (){
        webClient.callWebAdress();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This configuration now leads to a circular reference problem. However when I change the order of field `webClient` and `props` in my Application class everything works fine. I know there are several other options to get the code running e.g. autowiring the properties as method parameter, autowiring the properties Bean in the WebClient. But these are options which work fine for my simple example but they would reduce the legibility in my more complex code.

**I don't understand this questions regarding this issue:**

- Why is spring not able to find out the correct order of creating the beans?
- How can I structure multiple `Configuration` classes and `Components` in general?
- How can I structure the configuration to avoid issues regarding the autowiring order?

**references/dependencies of the beans to each other:**

[image]

*(orange means autowired, yellow means bean and white means component)*

Comment: Have you tried `@ConfigurationProperties`. Doc -  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Have you tried `@Bean String webAdress(Properties props){return "http://+"+props.getHost()+":"+props.getPort();}`

Comment: imho the biggest flaw is the fact that you try to make a simple property (`webAddress`) a bean which imho you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: sure, you all are right these are much better solutions regarding this simple WebClient example. Thanks for your ideas. But I cannot apply them to my more complex real world problem. Because there I have much more complex beans (not only String concatenation). It would be hard to inject every referenced bean as method parameter. I am looking forward to find a god solution to manage multiple configuration classes and components

Answer (score 0):

One Easy thing to do is separate this `@Bean` into differen *Configuration* class as below

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig{

 @Autowired
 WebClient webClient;


 @Bean
 String webAdresss(){
        return "http://+"+props.getHost()+":"+props.getPort();
 }

}
```